# How to enable "Ignore Application 4xx" on Apache Amazon Linux 2 Elastic Beanstalk Environment Health Check?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, custom-error-pages

I configured my Environment using Amazon Linux 2 with Apache server. My instance goes from OK to severe very frequently due to 4xx error. I am trying to enable "Ignore Application 4xx" on my environment but I didn't find the following option screen in my Health Monitoring page.

[image: Ignore]

My Health monitoring screen shows following options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404   http://websitename.com/404page.php
```

Comment: And make sure it is exact same file. Make sure file is having correct permission and it exist on that path

Comment: Thanks! My issue is on non-existence *.php files only. Have a look at my edited question.

Comment: You can try overriding the php document

`ProxyErrorOverride on`

So add the following to your httpd.conf or apache2.conf, not to your .htaccess.